# How to join arrays obtained with different numpy functions?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am writing a program to show the age of 100 people whose ages range between 18 and 110. I want to set a negative value for a couple of them and an age bigger than 120 for other 3 people, then clean the dataset setting 0 in these 5 "wrong" ages, and then check the minimum and the maximum of the ages after the cleaning.

I have a solution by setting the wrong ages individually, but I would like to be able to do this by creating one array with 95 elements (the correct ages), another with 5 elements (the wrong ages), and then concatenate them. However I don´t know how to concatenate 1-D arrays that were generated differently.

Here is my existing solution:

```
peopleAge = np.random.randint(18,110,100)
peopleAge[12] = -6
peopleAge[15] = -23
peopleAge[29] = 132
peopleAge[80] = 155
peopleAge[99] = 200
peopleAge = np.where((peopleAge < 0) | (peopleAge > 120), 0, peopleAge)

minAge = min(peopleAge[peopleAge > 0])
maxAge = max(peopleAge[peopleAge < 111])
```

And here is what I am trying to do:

```
peopleAge = np.random.randint(18,110,95)
peopleAgeSpecial = np.array([-6,-23,132,155,200])
```

How can I join peopleAge and peopleAgeSpecial into one array?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?  One option produces a (100,) shape array.

Comment: The result will look the same as shown in the existing solution, but the way to build the 100-item array will be different. I would like to know how I can arrive at the same result by concatenating two arrays.

Comment: You could either use a binary vector that selects the elements where you want to change you array or use the positions of the array directly

wrong_binary = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ... ,1, 0]) # something like that
peopleAge = np.random.randint(18,110,95)
peopleAge[wrong_binary] = np.array([-6,-23,132,155,200])
or
wrong = np.array([12, 15, 29, 80, 99])
peopleAge = np.random.randint(18,110,95)
peopleAge[wrong] = np.array([-6,-23,132,155,200])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to set the exact same index but just have five strange ages randomly distributed:

```
peopleAge = np.random.randint(18,110,95)
peopleAgeSpecial = np.array([-6,-23,132,155,200])

peopleAge = np.append(peopleAge, peopleAgeSpecial, axis = 0)
np.random.shuffle(peopleAge)
```